# freezing roquefort cheesecake cooked or uncooked

Tags: freezing

I'm making a roquefort cheesecake appetizer with roquefort, cream cheese, and eggs.  I'd like to cook 1/2 recipe now and freeze the other half for another time.  Do I cook the second half before freezing or after?
Thanks for your expert advice.

Comment: Are you intending to serve it cold or warm? *I* would assume cooking it first would work; if I wanted to serve it warm I'd take it out of the oven barely cooked to allow for further browning while reheating. And defrost in the fridge or it might get soggy from condensation. Comment rather than answer as based on assumptions.

Comment: Thanks...ended up cooking it.  Will put in fridge overnight and freeze in an to use at a later date.  Will be serving at room temp

Answer (score 1):

I would cook it first and store it in the freezer. Commercial entities that ship cheesecakes do it this way.  I would defrost in the refrigerator. Sounds delicious!  I hope it turns out well.